# Best way to launch Camera through a UITabBar

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios-camera

Many social media apps have a tab bar with a camera option in the middle. I want to implement this feature in my own `UITabViewController` I have succeeded to launch the camera when the `Tab Bar Item` is touched with the below code.

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {

    if item.title! == "Camera" {
        launchCamera()
    }
}
```

However, I am still new to swift and iOS development and I don't know if this is the best way to do this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Also, Once I do take the picture how do I go back to the tab I was at. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The best way to access devices is using AVFoundation library.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28892280/2332284

I hope it helps you